# I want to pass input value from one page and show search results in another page in algolia instant search?

Tags: algolia

I want to achieve just like this... https://magento.algolia.com/ when you search from home page and it will redirects you to result page along with the previous search value. I saw about the custom widgets of the instant search but cannot come over through. If I search 'shirt' over the above given site, the result page should be like this, https://magento.algolia.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=shirt

Comment: I have passed value from home page to search page but cannot start search over in the result page. When I am in result page, I can easily search over there.

Comment: Do you use Algolia Magento extension or do you have any other solution (your custom website)?

Comment: No, I am not using magento extension. I am doing project on laravel and using algolia with instant search. Just taking this site as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found solution,using the following parameters and then pass it to InstantSearch at initialization. searching_value van be fetched using javascript.

```
searchParameters:{
query: searching_value
}
```